# Multiple .active classes for navigation with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a very simple page that uses jQuery to hide and show content. I have 3 links, and 3 divs related to those 3 links. When you click one of the links that div get displayed. The jQuery script also adds a .active class to the link so I can show what link is currently active.

My problem is that I need to have 3 different .active classes, one for each link, so they can all have a different background image when it's active. Here is the jQuery code that runs it all:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[

  $(window).load(function(){

    $('.link').click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      // Remove any active classes:
      $('.active').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');

      // Hide all the content:
      $('.content').fadeOut();
      $('.logo').fadeOut(); 

      // Show the requested content:
      var content = $(this).attr('rel');
      $('#' + content).fadeIn();
    });

  });//]]>

</script>
```

I couldn't figure out how to create a jsfiddle, so I have a link to the dev page here: http://agoberg.tv/kiosk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I added 3 classes in the css, one for each link. Then I tweaked the jQuery to this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
// Catch all clicks on a link with the class 'link'
$('.link').click(function(e) {
// Stop the link being followed:
e.preventDefault();
// Get the div to be shown:
var content = $(this).attr('rel');
// Remove any active classes:
$('.activediv1').removeClass('activediv1');
$('.activediv2').removeClass('activediv2');
$('.activediv3').removeClass('activediv3');
// Add the 'active' class to this link:
$(this).addClass('active' + content);

// Hide all the content:
$('.content').fadeOut();
$('.logo').fadeOut(); 

// Show the requested content:
$('#' + content).fadeIn();

});
});//]]> 
</script>
```